# How to get a Twilio SMS body text in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, twilio, hapi.js

I'm working on a side-project of mine which integrates with Twilio. It's a Node.js app running on the Hapi.js framework.

I have the app set up with Twilio so that when I text my Twilio number, Twilio gets the request from my app's route and texts me back with a static message in the response.

What I'm having trouble with is getting the SMS body from the user's text. Let's say that I text the Twilio number with a word like `banana` I want to be able to retrieve that from the request so that I can have a dynamic message based on it.

I've tried `request.Body`, `request.message`, among several other things, and I can't seem to retrieve the user's text to the Twilio number. I've looked through Twilio's documentation and can't seem to figure it out. I saw [this PHP keyword tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-build-a-sms-keyword-response-application) on Twilio which looked promising, but even accessing `request.Body` as in that tutorial doesn't seem to work at all.

Does anyone know how to get the text body from a Twilio SMS that a user sends? Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: do you want set sms text dynamically ?

Comment: Sort of, I want the text that I send from a phone to my Twilio number, to be able to be parsed by Hapi and Node. Right now, Twilio just responds with a static message, the goal is to be able to respond differently based on the text sent to Twilio from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different methods to retrieve the request payload from Twilio, I found that the Twilio request body can be accessed via `request.url.query`, and therefore, the `Body` of the text, can be retrieved via `request.url.query.Body`. Thanks for the help @MattHarrison!

Comment: They must be encoding the message in the URL then as query string params. You don't need the `.url` part in that case. You can also use just `request.query.Body`, as Hapi will place the query params in there too.

Comment: I'll try that as well then! Thanks again for the insight into the Hapi framework, I'm really enjoying it!

Comment: Yeah you were right, `request.query.Body` works as well, thanks again @MattHarrison

Answer (score 1):

With Hapi, if you want to read all the `request` body into memory before running your `handler` you need to set the `payload` config:

```
server.route({
    config: {
        payload: {
            output: 'data'
        }
    },
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/textMessage',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        console.log('Body was', request.payload.toString()); 
        reply('...');
    }
});
```

From the Hapi API docs:

> 'data' - the incoming payload is read fully into memory. If parse is
>   true, the payload is parsed (JSON, form-decoded, multipart) based on
>   the 'Content-Type' header. If parse is false, the raw Buffer is
>   returned. This is the default value except when a proxy handler is
>   used.

More options here: http://hapijs.com/api#route-options

Comment: That looks interesting, this is my first time using the Hapi framework, I wasn't aware of that fact, let me try it and I'll post back, thanks for the insight and response!

Comment: I've configured the route using your suggestion and now the `request.payload` is now `null`, and `request.payload.toString()` returns an error as a result...weird. Do you know what it could be? I thought that this would've parsed the Twilio payload

Comment: Can you use something like wireshark or fiddler to confirm there is indeed a payload being sent?

Comment: Ahh I found the answer, it seems it can be accessed using the following object `request.url.query.Body`