# Unable to get the GET data from Twilio requesst

Tags: node.js, rest, meteor, twilio, body-parser

EDITED.

Once again, I don't know how to solve this (simple, I'm sure) problem. Maybe you could show me a path.. : I'm unable to get the "body" of a rest GET request.

More precisely:

1. I send an SMS from my phone to my Twilio number
2. This inbounding message 'fires' a request URL (http get) from Twilio to my app
3. My app server 'catches' the data (message body, sender, timestamp...) and 'fires back' a confirmation SMS...

Super simple!

- No problem with (1) --> hopefully!
- No problem with (2)
- But, with (3), the confirmation SMS is well sent, but I can't access the data (my log in my terminal always shows me two curly empty brackets...)

Any idea what's going on?

Thank you very much..

```
  var bodyParser = Meteor.npmRequire( 'body-parser' );

Picker.middleware( bodyParser.json() );
Picker.middleware( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) );

Picker.route( '/documents', function( params, request, response, next ) {

    if (client.findOne({_id:"EJB3KDgTwBzvoe3y6"})){
        console.log("blabla");
        // with just 'params' I get something verbose in my terminal, including my message, but I don't know how to 'catch' it
        console.log( request.body );
        // messages.insert({
        //     message: request....
        // });
        response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/xml' );
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.end( "<Response><Message>Bonjour, I'm becky</Message></Response>" );
    }

    else {
        response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/xml' );
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.end( "<Response><Message>Hello, don't knou you..</Message></Response>" );
    }
});
```

EDIT 2 :
This is what I get in my Terminal (Meteor)

```
I20160228-16:53:22.209(1)? { query: 
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?    { ToCountry: 'FR',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      ToState: '',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      SmsMessageSid: 'SMf8eae81eb0f2bd',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      NumMedia: '0',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      ToCity: '',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      FromZip: '',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      SmsSid: 'SMf8eae81eb0f2bd',
I20160228-16:53:22.210(1)?      FromState: '',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      SmsStatus: 'received',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      FromCity: '',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      Body: 'my message I want to catch and store in my db',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      FromCountry: 'FR',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      To: '+xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      ToZip: '',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      NumSegments: '1',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      MessageSid: 'SMf8eae81eb',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      AccountSid: 'AC72924a656',
I20160228-16:53:22.211(1)?      From: '+xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
I20160228-16:53:22.212(1)?      ApiVersion: '2010-04-01' } }
```

Comment: Have you tried `request.url.query.Body` according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017970/how-to-get-a-twilio-sms-body-text-in-node-js?rq=1

Comment: What is the exact URL Twilio is sending to you?  Maybe stuff is being sent in the params considering it's a GET request.

Comment: I think it's something like this : http://myserver/callhandler.php?Body=How+are+you+doing&From=4158675309&To=4155551212&AccountSid=AC394848B8393DF323 (as seen in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/2008-08-01/twiml/sms/twilio_request). I do not know how to see a real request (made on my app)... request.url.query.Body doesn't seem to work either :-/

Comment: I've just edited my post : see the code "with just 'params' I get something verbose in my terminal, including my message, but I don't know how to 'catch' it"... It makes me crazy

Comment: If this is the result of `console.log( request.body )`, doesn't using `request.body.query.Body` work?

Comment: If you have solved your issue, please post an answer explaining how. Do not show that your issue is solved with an edit.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. @nerotulip is this question solved yet? Or can I help?